# PHP + postfix: all emails copied to mailer-daemon

Tags: php, postfix-mta

I have an ubuntu 12.10 box with latest repository (apt-get) postfix. When I send emails from `sendmail` command line:

```
sendmail -r from@example.com -f from@example.com -t to@example.com
```

The email is sent only to `to@example.com` (and this is good).

However, when I use PHP and this function:

```
function mymail($to, $subject, $message, $frommail = "from@example.com", $fromname = "From Me") {
  $subject = "=?utf-8?B?" . base64_encode($subject) . "?=";
  $from = $fromname . " <" . $frommail . ">";
  $headers = "From: " . $from . " \r\n";
  $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
  $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n";
  $headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n\r\n";
  $message = base64_encode($message);
  $param = "-r " . $frommail . " \r\n";
  // Optionally tried also 
  // $param = "-r " . $frommail . " -f " . $frommail . " \r\n";
  mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers, $param);
}
```

then `to@example.com` **AND** MAILER-DAEMON (which I set to root in my `aliases`) receives the email.

The MAILER-DAEMON email when read by the mailutils `mail` command is:

```
Return-Path: <from@example.com>
Delivered-To: MAILER-DAEMON@localhost
Received: by localhost (Postfix, from userid 33)
    id 5663254EB; Wed, 15 May 2013 16:57:52 +0700 (ICT)
To: to@example
Subject: Test
X-PHP-Originating-Script: 1000:mail_func.php
From: FromMe <from@example.com> 
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Message-Id: <20130515095752.5663254EB@localhost>
Date: Wed, 15 May 2013 16:57:52 +0700 (ICT)
```

followed by the base64 email.
How can I prevent MAILER-DAEMON to receive a copy when sending email by PHP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure I should delete this question or let it for future help. I just found the reason. In the extra parameters, I should use

```
$param = "-f" . $frommail;
```

and without `."\r\n"` instead of the wrong:

```
$param = "-r " . $frommail . " \r\n";
```